# Cannot redeclare function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, lazy-loading, redeclare

I have a following function in one of the files for this plugin "BJ lazy load".

```
<?php

function bjll_compat_operamini() {
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) && false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'bjll/enabled', '__return_false' );
    }
}

add_action( 'bjll/compat', 'bjll_compat_operamini' );
```

And for some reason, I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare bjll_compat_operamini() (previously declared in /home/brbzdksz/public_html/abeyuto.com/wp-content/plugins/bj-lazy-load/inc/compat/opera-mini.php:4) in /home/brbzdksz/public_html/abeyuto.com/wp-content/plugins/bj-lazy-load/inc/compat/opera-mini.php on line 4

What I can't figure out here is how this function is being declared twice on the same line, which is line 4.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, this file is being loaded twice  -- meaning that the problem is not in this code. If you are using "require" to load the file, you can fix this simply by using "require_once" instead.

Comment: Thank you. I will check if there's "require" part somewhere.

Comment: also don't put your functions inside template-parts, if you use them inside loop